# How can I upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04?

Tags: upgrade

I want to Upgrade my Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Switch on your computer with Ubuntu 12.04, (presumably 12.04.4 if you have updated all till now), and logon.

Do not open any application. Open 'Software Updater' from Dash. It would check for updates and upgrades.

Follow all the instruction from it. Depending on the speed of your internet connection, you may have to wait for some time.

I upgraded to 14.04 LTS this way, and hope it works for you as well. Wonder of wonders! It is a seamless operation. Everything in my computer remained intact and working, except Google Earth 7.X, which is crashing till date.